# Why can Mathematica detect a linear term in a series expansion only in special cases?

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion

The series expansion

```
Series[Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[d k]], {k, 0, 5}]
```

Is in odd powers of `Abs[k]`, or more precisely `Sqrt[k^2]`. But the same function with some extra parameters only yields even powers of `k` in the series expansion

```
Series[Sqrt[-c - 2 b Cos[d k] - 2 a Cos[2 d k]], {k, 0, 5}]
```

What's going on here? If I do the variable substitution `/. {c -> -2, a -> 0, b -> 1}` I again get powers of `Abs[k]`. The variable substitution also does not commute with the series expansion; if I do the substitution after expanding I get

```
ComplexInfinity k^2 + Indeterminate k^4 + O[k]^6.
```

Comment: Making a note: You can get a series expansion in `Abs[k]` from the one in even powers of `k` by solving for values of the parameters which make the second-order coefficient blow up, then substituting these values into the function and expanding again. Kind of a crappy way to deal with the issue though and I'm definitely interested in any better ideas.

Comment: In the first case you're expanding at a singularity and in the second, `Series` makes a generic assumption that you're not. In a sense, there's no "mistake," if you will, because the `ComplexInfinity` and `Indeterminate` you get in `series /. c -> -2 a - 2 b` shows there's a problem if you try to specialize to a singularity.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for the explanation! In this case the behavior was undesirable since I was solving a problem that involved matching the parameters $a,b,c$ to coefficients in a dispersion relation $\omega \sim v |k|+O(k^5)$. Is the only way to obtain this kind of expansion by using the hack I used?

Comment: Can you replace `c` by `-2(a+b)` and fit the parameters other than `c` to the singular expansion?  Maybe compare that with the analytic expansion and see which fits better? If you compare the simpler `Normal@Series[Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[x]], {x, 0, 5}] // N` and `Normal@Series[Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[x]], {x, x0, 5}] /. 
  x0 -> 0.0001 // Expand`, you'll see that the coefficients of the analytic expansion does not approach the singular ones as `x0` approaches `0`.  So I think you have to consider the two cases (or just the singular one).

Comment: I'm guessing you want to restrict to positive `k`. If so, you can get a more targeted result with `Series[Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[d k]], {k, 0, 5}, Assumptions -> {k > 0}]`